# Running a (python) script in another directory

Tags: python, linux, bash, gnu-make

I have a python script, which generates files. All i want is to force it to write the files in a specific folder. Right now i have to do 3 steps:

```
cd foo
python ../awesome_script.py
cd ..
```

Is there any nice solution, where i can do this in one line, either using some external command, or directly in the python interpreter?

I am searching for something like:

```
python -f foo awesome_script.py
```

or

```
cd_in_and_out_program foo awesome_script.py
```

This instruction will be in a makefile afterwards, so it can be ugly.

Comment: `(cd foo && python awesome_script.py)`  (with the parenthesises)

Comment: if you wrote to stdout ie print() you could do somethong like python foo.py > /path/to/file.mk

Comment: @MattJoyce no, i am creating files

Comment: You could do as @MattJoyce suggests (my preferred solution since it allows the script to be more flexible) or you could take the output folder as a command line argument which defaults to the current directory.

Comment: @spectras has probably the best version, and he is absolutely right with the duplicate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is just "one line":

```
cd foo; python ../awesome_script.py; cd ..
```

will do

Comment: yeah sure, but i am asking, whether there is a smart alternative